# What do x. L. T. D. in python documentation mean?

Tags: python

If I use pydoc to detail an object (pydoc sys.argv, in this example), the examples are generally listed as so:

```
 append(...)
 |      L.append(object) -- append object to end

 __add__(...)
 |      x.__add__(y) <==> x+y
```

What do the L. and x. notate?

Answer (score 1):

The `sys.argv` is actually a `list`, so pydoc is showing you the documentation for `list`. In this case, the free variables in the examples (`L`, `x`, `y`) represent lists.